# How many answers does the equation $\sin{x}+\lfloor{\sin{x}}\rfloor=\frac{x}{3}+\lfloor{\frac{x}{3}}\rfloor$have?(using gragh)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many answers does the equation $\sin{x}+\lfloor{\sin{x}}\rfloor=\frac{x}{3}+\lfloor{\frac{x}{3}}\rfloor$have(using gragh)?

Please help me I am stuck in drawing $\sin{x}+\lfloor{\sin{x}}\rfloor$and $\frac{x}{3}+\lfloor{\frac{x}{3}}\rfloor$ an dfind their intersections how should I work?

Comment: take a look here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7Bfloor(sin+x)%2Bsin(x),x%2F3%2Bfloor(x%2F3)%7D+for+x%3D-10+to+10

Comment: @Math-fun How should we count the intersections by hand drawing?

Comment: when drawing by hand then you should be very careful, then yo ucould see all the intersections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph of $$ \sin x+ \lfloor \sin x \rfloor = \frac {x}{3} + \lfloor \frac {x}{3} \rfloor $$ is as follows (the red curves are for $\sin x +\lfloor \sin x \rfloor $ and the blue lines for $\frac {x}{3} +\lfloor \frac {x}{3} \rfloor $) :

[image]

If you want the intersection points,

[image]

---

Hope it helps.

Comment: $(0,-1)$ is not a solution. both functions are "void" at this point :-)

Comment: @Math-fun That's why I said intersection points while describing the second graph.

Comment: maybe I don't see your point, but the functions do not intersent at this point.